# Error: The type or namespace name 'SqlCe' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to export my data from a dataGridView to an excel file. It works like charm, but I just want to have the name of the columns too. I wrote the following code, but I can't get it with this error. Thanks !

> Error: The type or namespace name 'SqlCe' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
foreach (SqlCe.Data.DataColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
                colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1);

xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment= Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
```

The reference for SQL Server CE: `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;`

Comment: "The reference for SQLServerCe: using System.Data.SqlServerCe" - that's not a reference, it's a using directive for a namespace. In your project in solution explorer, under "references", do you have the right assembly listed *there*?

Comment: Marked this question as a duplicate of that one as there's no indication that it's different at the moment.

Comment: Actually, no, I'm wrong - it *is* different...

Comment: It is different by the fact that I'm using SQLServerCe above but only here I'm getting this error. That's why I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The problem is that you're referring to a type/namespace that doesn't exist. Where do you think the `SqlCe` type or namespace is? What made you think that code *would* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* no type called `SqlCe` as far as I can see... for the `DataColumn` type, you should just be using [`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn), ideally via a `using` directive for `System.Windows.Forms`. Note that `DataGridViewColumn` doesn't have a `ColumnName` property, but it does have a `Name` property:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
foreach (DataGridViewColumn  dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    colNames[col++] = dc.Name;
}
```

There's no need to refer to `SqlCe` there, because a `DataGridView` isn't provider-specific.

Also note that if `colNames` *just* contains these column names, you could use:

```
var colNames = dataGridView1.Columns
                            .Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                            .Select(c => c.Name)
                            .ToArray(); // Or ToList
```

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to type 'System.Data.DataColumn'.`  This error I'm getting right now.

Comment: @user3348368: Okay, so you don't want `DataColumn` at all. You want `DataGridViewColumn`. I'll edit. It's still not clear to me what type you thought you *were* referring to.

Comment: `'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnName' and no extension method 'ColumnName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  .. and now this.

Comment: @user3348368: Yes, see my answer - you need to use `Name` not `ColumnName`, as you could have found out fairly simply by reading the documentation.

Comment: `A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' is a type not a namespace ` why?

Comment: @user3348368: Um, well it's not a namespace. Note that my code has `using System.Windows.Forms;` not `using System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn;`. If you're confused about the differences between namespaces and types (and assembly references) I suggest you read a good book about C# so you understand the basics before you go any further in GUI and database work, which have their own gotchas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88150/discussion-between-user3348368-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: Got that. Working properly now, just the fact the it adds at each column name `orelunaDataGridViewTextBoxColumn`. I'll solve it. I understand the errors, and all about this. But just that I don't know exactly a solution all the time for them. Thanks a lot !